# Nav height being 0px when at auto?

Tags: html, css, nav

I'm new and learning how to code in HTML and CSS and I encountered a problem whilst trying to make a Navigation bar. The problem is as followed:I set the 
*background-color* of my nav to red yet I don't see it. It's acting like the navigation bars height is 0px and I don't know why. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

```css
body{
 margin:0;
}

nav ul{
 margin:0;
}

nav{
 margin-top:0px;
 background-color:red;
 height:auto;
}

header img{
 height:45px;
 width: 45px;
 display:block;
 margin:auto;
}

nav ul li{

 display:inline-block;
}
nav ul div{

 display:block;
}

nav ul li a{
 display:block;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-left:20px;
 margin-right:40px;
 padding:10px;
 border:1px solid black;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

header{
 background-color:#BACFEB;
 height: auto;
}

header h1{
 font-family: cursive;
 margin:0;
 text-align: center;
}

#right{
 float:right;
}


#left{
 float:left;
}

/*footer ul{

margin:auto;
}

footer ul li{

display: inline-block;

}*/


/*CSS works*/
nav ul li a:hover{

text-decoration:underline;
font-family: Arial;
color:red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <div id="left">
      <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"> About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"> Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <li><a href="#"> Sign in</a>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: It looks red here.

Comment: I editted your post to feature a snippet instead of "just" code, in which I can't see any problems - I see the red background, and some blue text and borders around buttons. Maybe you have some additional CSS that interferes with this?

Comment: This is your code, it is red https://jsfiddle.net/1Lve1foo/

Comment: Nothing's wrong with this. By the way, `height: auto` is the default value. You don't need to specify it.

Comment: May be your page is cashed by your browser, click ctrl+F5 to refresh it. Or clear the browser cash.

Comment: Updated to the full css file. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3):

Because all of your contents of `.nav` are floating, you need `overflow: hidden` to make sure the outer element correctly spans around all child elements.

```
nav {
  margin-top:0px;
  background-color:red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Never make overflow: hidden to your nav. If you want to add dropdowns to your nav (when your site will develop), dropdowns will be hidden.

Comment: @Olga: I agree that `overflow:hidden` would interfere with absolute positioned elements, however I neither agree that as a general rule, `overflow:hidden` shouldn't be applied to nav elements (as it's perfectly legal by the CSS definition, and should be applied as needed from there) nor that it shouldn't be in this case, as two things speak for it's usage: The questioner uses float elements and wants the parent container to wrap around them, and there are no dropdown elements in the question.

Comment: No need to use `overflow: hidden`, or `overflow: auto`, when there is a standard way of clearing `float`'s, by simply clear the float. Just made an update of my answer with that.

Comment: @LGSon: It's a possible solution, though I'm not sure creating additional overhead by introducing a new :after element (with table display besides) is "needed" more than a single overflow property on an already existing element.

Comment: Clearing float doesn't hide overflowed content, so IMHO it's a no-brainer (and it uses `display:block`). Could elaborate on how that _overhead_ will be that big of an issue, because if it is, I will strongly consider avoiding it.

Comment: @LGSon: It wasn't a phrase when I said that I don't know which is better, so I can't elabrotate on it much. My thoughts are that a single property is likely less resource-intensive than a pseudo-element with three properties. It's no no-brainer either, because what you and Olga are doing is preparing for the *theoretical* case that someone wants a dropdown menu, while you're ignoring that someone might need another after pseudo-element on the nav element. CSS always has to be applied depending on the situation, and my answer fixes the exact problem at hand in the (to my knowledge) best manner.

Comment: Thanks, it is all about the angle of things :)

Answer (score 1):

Updated

That is caused by the floated `div`'s, which also are invalid, as one aren't allowed to have a `div` as a direct child of an `ul`

*Note: In below samples I updated the markup*

You solve that by clearing the `float`'s ([well explained here](http://cssmojo.com/the-very-latest-clearfix-reloaded/))

```
nav:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both
}
```

```css
body{
 margin:0;
}
nav ul{
 margin:0;
}
nav{
 margin-top:0px;
 background-color:red;
 height:auto;
}
header img{
 height:45px;
 width: 45px;
 display:block;
 margin:auto;
}
nav ul li{
 display:inline-block;
}
nav ul div{
 display:block;
}
nav ul li a{
 display:block;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-left:20px;
 margin-right:40px;
 padding:10px;
 border:1px solid black;
 border-radius: 10px;
}
header{
 background-color:#BACFEB;
 height: auto;
}
header h1{
 font-family: cursive;
 margin:0;
 text-align: center;
}
#right{
 float:right;
}
#left{
 float:left;
}
nav:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both
}

/*footer ul{

margin:auto;
}

footer ul li{


display: inline-block;

}*/


/*CSS works*/
nav ul li a:hover{
  text-decoration:underline;
  font-family: Arial;
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="left">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"> About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"> Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"> Sign in</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

May I suggest you do like this, using `flex` instead of `float`.

If you can't use `flex`, `display:table-cell` will do pretty much the same (Sample 2 below)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
}
nav {
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: red;
  height: auto;
}
nav {
  display: flex;
}
header img {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav ul div {
  display: block;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
header {
  background-color: #BACFEB;
  height: auto;
}
header h1 {
  font-family: cursive;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
/*CSS works*/

nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="left">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"> About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"> Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"> Sign in</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

Sample 2

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
}
nav {
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: red;
  height: auto;
}
nav > div {
  display: table-cell;
}
header img {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
nav ul div {
  display: block;
}
nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
header {
  background-color: #BACFEB;
  height: auto;
}
header h1 {
  font-family: cursive;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
/*CSS works*/

nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="left">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"> About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"> Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#"> Sign in</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The DIVs `#left` and `#right` in your navbar are floated. Floated elements don't take any vertical space in their containers, that's why the height of the container is 0.

There is a method though: Assign `overflow: hidden;`to the container, i.e. to the `ul`

```css
body{
 margin:0;
}

nav ul{
 margin:0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav{
 margin-top:0px;
 background-color:red;
 height:auto;
}

header img{
 height:45px;
 width: 45px;
 display:block;
 margin:auto;
}

nav ul li{

 display:inline-block;
}
nav ul div{

 display:block;
}

nav ul li a{
 display:block;
 text-decoration: none;
 margin-left:20px;
 margin-right:40px;
 padding:10px;
 border:1px solid black;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

header{
 background-color:#BACFEB;
 height: auto;
}

header h1{
 font-family: cursive;
 margin:0;
 text-align: center;
}

#right{
 float:right;
}


#left{
 float:left;
}

/*footer ul{

margin:auto;
}

footer ul li{

display: inline-block;

}*/


/*CSS works*/
nav ul li a:hover{

text-decoration:underline;
font-family: Arial;
color:red;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <div id="left">
      <li><a href="index.htm">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"> About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"> Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <li><a href="#"> Sign in</a>
      </li>
    </div>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

because of `float: left` and `float: right` split thing

you put it inside `ul` you must `clear: both` in end of `ul`

> try this

put this `div` inside ul but on latest of it

`<div style="clear:both;"></div>`

Comment: Not only is this utterly redundant as the other answers are showing, but also introduces a non-valid element, as `ul`s may only have `li`s as their direct children. As a general rule, while they do have their applications, I would avoid using clear elements anywhere to get a cleaner markup and better maintainability.